# How to include Featured Posts in the loop in Wordpress Twenty Fourteen

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Child-Theme of Wordpress Twenty Fourteen and I want to have the featured posts, that are displayed in the grid above the main blog-area, not to disappear in the blog-area. so the should appear in the grid AND in the blog-loop.

I already searched the theme's files, but I didn't get the clue, where the featured posts are filtered.

I also tried to get rid of unnecessary complexity and created a new index.php for the child-theme:

```
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );

            endwhile;

        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
    ?>
```

but even there the featured posts are missing. (It shows only the main loop).

Any idea where to do the trick?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 24.10.:**
After I couldn't solve my problem with the recent two answers, I further investigated the original twenty fourteen theme and found the file *inc/featured-content.php*, in which the featured content gets filtered.

The function pre_get_posts in ll. 231 ff. is responsible for this issue - on purpose, but with no hint, how to *not* filter.

I assume, as *inc/featured-content.php* contains a class, I could extend it and 
overwrite the pre_get_posts-method?

But actually, I'm no php-guru and I don't see, where the original class is initialized...? Any ideas?

**Follow-Up update:**
In functions.php, ll. 514 ff., the Class in question is required:

```
/*
 * Add Featured Content functionality.
 *
 * To overwrite in a plugin, define your own Featured_Content class on or
 * before the 'setup_theme' hook.
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Featured_Content' ) && 'plugins.php' !== $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/featured-content.php';
}
```

this seems to be a problem to simply override it? It would be good, not to loose the whole class's functionality, but only to alter it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a working solution (actually, before I tried it, but used the wrong hook... :-/ ):

In my child's `functions.php` I added these lines to remove the filtering function from the `Featured_Content` class in `inc/featured-content.php`

```
function do_not_filter_featured_posts() {
 remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( 'Featured_Content', 'pre_get_posts' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'do_not_filter_featured_posts' );
```

This adds a function `do_not_filter_featured_posts` to be called after wordpress is loaded, which removes the function `pre_get_posts` added inside the parent theme's class `Featured_Content` on hook `pre_get_posts`.

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
<?php

    $fp_arg = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'meta_key' => 'featured_product', // the name of the custom field
                    'meta_compare' => '=', // the comparison (e.g. equals, does not equal, etc...)
                    'meta_value' => 1, // the value to which the custom field is compared. In my case, 'featured_product' was a true/false checkbox. If you had a custom field called 'color' and wanted to show only those blue items, then the meta_value would be 'blue'
                    );

    $future_post = new wp_query($fp_arg);

 ?>

<?php if ( $future_post->have_posts() ){
         while ( $future_post->have_posts() ) : $future_post->the_post();
                 the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                 }

        endwhile;
}
 ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance - but I couldn't solve my problem yet. Maybe you have any ideas for my updated question?